# Excluir fechas con LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo la siguiente consulta con LINQ esta me funciona muy bien

```
 List<Vehiculos> ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Vehiculos>>(response.Content);
          var m = ob.Max(x => x.number);
                Num = m;
                dataGridView5.DataSource = (from o in ob
                                            where o.number == m  
                                            orderby o.number descending
                                            select o).ToList();
```

ahora lo que necesito es excluir son unos meses es decir decirle a la consulta que no me muestre el mes de enero y de febrero **workshopDate** contiene las fechas de una lista es decir en ese **workshopDate** hay varios registros con fechas de enero febrero y marzo lo que hice en esta consulta fue traer el mes menor  que seria mes 1 es lo que queda en f, pero no es así como tiene que quedar, como decía anteriormente necesito es  de ese **workshopDate** no mostrar el mes de enero y febrero mostrar de marzo en adelante peor no logro hacerlo

```
 List<Vehiculos> ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Vehiculos>>(response.Content);
  var f = ob.Min(x => x.workshopDate.Month);
  nvar m = ob.Max(x => x.number);
  Num = m;
  dataGridView5.DataSource = (from o in ob
                             where o.number == m && o.workshopDate.Month == f
                             orderby o.number descending
                             select o).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var lista  = (from o in ob
              where o.number == m
              orderby o.number descending
              select new
              {
                  o.number,
                  Fechas = o.workshopDate.Where(x => x.Month > 2).ToList()
              }).ToList();
```

Lo que se hace aquí es una consulta que va a devolver un **objeto anónimo** que va a tener **dos propiedades**: **number** y **Fechas**. Como dices que **workshopDate es una lista de fechas** y de estas solo quieres obtener las que tienen el mes mayor que **2**(No vas a obtener las fechas cuyo mes sea enero(**1**) y febrero(**2**)),entonces se hace un **where** que va a seleccionar de esta lista de fechas las que cumplen con la condición que deseas:

```
Fechas = o.workshopDate.Where(x => x.Month > 2).ToList()
```

**Fechas** va a guardar solo las fechas cuyo mes es mayor que **2**.